# Use Google Sign In to authorize YouTube Data API

Tags: java, android, youtube, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I've been following [this article](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) to implement Google Sign-In into an Android app.

This final bit of code gives us a `GoogleSignInAccount` object that contains information about the signed-in user:

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
```

In all of the [code samples provided](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) for the YouTube Data API, the following authentication code is used:

```
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = ApiExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader( in ));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
        .setAccessType("offline")
        .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
    flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    System.out.println(
        "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}
```

Now because I've already authenticated using Google Sign-In, how can I create a `Credential` object using the `GoogleSignInAccount` object to pass to [`YouTube.Builder`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/YouTube.Builder.html)?

Comment: I'll write an answer for this question later, but in the mean time, [this](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/7d323b09af889f5c03b862612c796046) helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static final Collection<String> YOUTUBE_SCOPE = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner");

...

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

    ...

    GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, YOUTUBE_SCOPE);
    credential.setSelectedAccount(acct.getAccount());

    ...

}
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/7d323b09af889f5c03b862612c796046#file-restapiactivity-java-L284)